# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution with two projects (a Word-Template project and a VB.Net console application for testing).  Both projects reference a database project which opens a connection to an MS-Access 2007 database file and have references to System.Data.OleDb.  In the database project I have a function which retrieves a data table as follows

```
 private class AdminDatabase
   ' stores the connection string which is set in the New() method
   dim strAdminConnection as string

   public sub New()
   ...
   adminName = dlgopen.FileName
   conAdminDB = New OleDbConnection
   conAdminDB.ConnectionString = "Data Source='" + adminName + "';" + _
       "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

   ' store the connection string in strAdminConnection
   strAdminConnection = conAdminDB.ConnectionString.ToString()
   My.Settings.SetUserOverride("AdminConnectionString", strAdminConnection)
   ...
   End Sub

   ' retrieves data from the database
   Public Function getDataTable(ByVal sqlStatement As String) As DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim localCon As New OleDbConnection


        localCon.ConnectionString = strAdminConnection

        Using localCon
            Dim command As OleDbCommand = localCon.CreateCommand()
            command.CommandText = sqlStatement
            localCon.Open()
            da.SelectCommand = command
            da.Fill(dt)
            getDataTable = dt
        End Using

    End Function
End Class
```

When I call this function from my Word 2007 Template project everything works fine; no errors. But when I run it from the console application it throws the following exception

> ex = {"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
>   provider is not registered on the
>   local machine."}

Both projects have the same reference and the console application did work when I first wrote it (a while ago) but now it has stopped work.  I must be missing something but I don't know what.  Any ideas?

Comment: Im also facing the same problem. can you guys please help me?
where i'll find the installer of 2007 access database provider?

Comment: see -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have a visual Basic program with Visual Studio 2008 that uses an Access 2007 database and was receiving the same error. I found some threads that advised changing the advanced compile configuration to x86 found in the programs properties if you're running a 64 bit system. So far I haven't had any problems with my program since.

Comment: But for an asp.net application this is determined by the IIS, so check out this article: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435/en-us

Comment: I was having the same problem on an ASP.NET application - running the code locally worked, but failed on the server.  Needed to install 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en, then had to enable the worker process (application pool) for the web site to allow 32-bit applications.

Comment: This doesn't help people who can't use x86.  There is a version of ACE for 64-bit: http://goo.gl/Cxsf1, but you have to uninstall Office 2003 because there are compatibility issues there.

Comment: I have 64 bit OS and Office 2010 x86 version with access db engine redistributor installed, i am trying to fix the error with all possible solution in the internet..but its not working. I also have another project where the same provider works.

Answer (score 53):

Basically, if you're on a 64-bit machine, IIS 7 is not (by default) serving 32-bit apps, which the database engine operates on. So here is exactly what you do:

1) ensure that the 2007 database engine is installed, this can be downloaded at:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en

2) open IIS7 manager, and open the Application Pools area. On the right sidebar, you will see an option that says "Set application pool defaults". Click it, and a window will pop up with the options.

3) the second field down, which says 'Enable 32-bit applications' is probably set to FALSE by default. Simply click where it says 'false' to change it to 'true'.

4) Restart your app pool (you can do this by hitting RECYCLE instead of STOP then START, which will also work).

5) done, and your error message will go away.

Comment: This worked for me... Visual Studio 2010 Premium, Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7, using WCF in a tiered web application.

Comment: Keep in mind this means the App Pool will run entirely in 32 bit mode with this flag.

Comment: Microsoft link is dead. If anyone is looking for a replacement link to the 2007 database engine. It's hosted at download.com here: https://download.cnet.com/2007-Office-System-Driver-Data-Connectivity-Components/3000-10254_4-75452798.html

It's legit. The joys of legacy software maintenance.

Answer (score 7):

Are you running a 64 bit system with the database running 32 bit but the console running 64 bit? There are no MS Access drivers that run 64 bit and would report an error identical to the one your reported.

Comment: Yes, I am running 64bit XP and this was exactly the problem. Switched the target CPU in Advanced Compile Options to x86 bit application and all works now. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

---

**Solution:**

That's it!  Thanks Arjun Paudel for the link.  Here's the solution as found on XNA Creator's Club Online.  It's by Stephen Styrchak.

The following error suggests me to believe that you are compiling for 64bit:

> The 'Microsoft .ACE.OELDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

I dont have express edition but are following steps valid in 2008 express?

http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/4377.aspx#22601

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/ed374d4f-5677-41cb-bfe0-198e68810805/?prof=required
- Arjun Paudel

---

In `VC# Express`, this property is missing, but you can still create an x86 configuration if you know where to look.

It looks like a long list of steps, but once you know where these things are it's a lot easier. Anyone who only has `VC# Express` will probably find this useful. Once you know about `Configuration Manager`, it'll be much more intuitive the next time.

1.In VC# Express 2005, go to `Tools -> Options`.
2.In the bottom-left corner of the Options dialog, check the box that says, `"Show all settings"`.
3.In the tree-view on the left hand side, select `"Projects and Solutions"`.
4.In the options on the right, check the box that says, `"Show advanced build configuraions."`
5.Click `OK`.
6.Go to `Build -> Configuration Manager`...
7.In the Platform column next to your project, click the combobox and select `"<New...>"`.
8.In the `"New platform" setting, choose "x86"`.
9.Click `OK`.
10.Click `Close`.
There, now you have an x86 configuration! Easy as pie! :-)

I also recommend using `Configuration Manager` to delete the Any CPU platform. You really don't want that if you ever have depedencies on 32-bit native DLLs (even indirect dependencies).

Stephen Styrchak | XNA Game Studio Developer 
http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/4377/22601.aspx#22601

---

Comment: Thanks for the additional info and detailed explanation on changing the compiler target (x86 or 64bit).

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd chime in because I found this question when facing a slightly different context of the problem and thought it might help other tormented souls in the future:

I had an ASP.NET app hosted on IIS 7.0 running on Windows Server 2008 64-bit.

Since IIS is in control of the process bitness, the solution in my case was to set the Enable32bitAppOnWin64 setting to true:
http://blogs.msdn.com/vijaysk/archive/2009/03/06/iis-7-tip-2-you-can-now-run-32-bit-and-64-bit-applications-on-the-same-server.aspx

It works slightly differently in IIS 6.0 (You cannot set Enable32bitAppOnWin64 at application-pool level)
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0aafb9a0-1b1c-4a39-ac9a-994adc902485.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 2):

I'm having same problem. I try to install office 2010 64bit on windows 7 64 bit and then install 2007 Office System Driver : Data Connectivity Components.

after that, visual studio 2008 can opens a connection to an MS-Access 2007 database file.

Answer (score 2):

See my post on a similar Stack Exchange thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/21455677/1368849

I had version 15, not 12 installed, which I found out by running this PowerShell code...

```
(New-Object system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator).GetElements() | select SOURCES_NAME, SOURCES_DESCRIPTION
```

...which gave me this result (I've removed other data sources for brevity)...

```
SOURCES_NAME              SOURCES_DESCRIPTION                                                                       
------------              -------------------                                                                       
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0  Microsoft Office 15.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error on a fully updated Windows Vista Family 64bit with a .NET application that I've compiled to 32 bit only - the program is installed in the programx86 folder on 64 bit machines. It fails with this error message even with  2007 access database provider installed, with/wiothout the SP2 of the same installed, IIS installed and app pool set for 32bit app support... yes I've tried every solution everywhere and still no success.

I switched my app to ACE OLE DB.12.0 because JET4.0 was failing on 64bit machines - and it's no better :-/ The most promising thread I've found was this:

http://ellisweb.net/2010/01/connecting-to-excel-and-access-files-using-net-on-a-64-bit-server/

but when you try to install the 64 bit "2010 Office System Driver Beta: Data Connectivity Components" it tells you that you can't install the 64 bit version without uninstalling all 32bit office applications... and installing the 32 bit version of  2010 Office System Driver Beta: Data Connectivity Components  doesn't solve the initial problem, even with "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" as provider instead of "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0" which that page (and others) recommend.

My next attempt will be to follow this post:

The issue is due to the wrong flavor of OLEDB32.DLL and OLEDB32r.DLL being registered on the server.  If the 64 bit versions are registered, they need to be unregistered, and then the 32 bit versions registered instead.   To fix this, unregister the versions located in %Program Files%/Common Files/System/OLE DB.  Then register the versions at the same path but in the %Program Files (x86)% directory.

Has anyone else had so much trouble with both JET4.0 and OLEDB ACE providers on 64 bit machines? Has anyone found a solution if none of the others work?

Comment: There is useful information here, but as you by now know, this writing style isn't the preferred one for stackexchange. If you cleaned this up (and maybe updated what ended up working for you, if you still remember), this would add to the question, especially since there are so few references to versions after 12.0 (and whether they should be used) currently on the network. Or, at least, I would appreciate the update.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that if you are running a 64 bit system with a 32 bit database and trying to run a 64 bit console, the following packages need to be installed on the machine.

1. Install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 x86
   Redistributable, this installation is available at:
   http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255 .
2. Data Connectivity Components of Office 2007, this installation is
   available at:
   http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 .
3. Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 x64 Redistributable.  You will
   need to download the package locally and run it with a passive flag.
   You can download the installation here:
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
   Installing using the command prompt with the '/passive' flag. In the
   command prompt run the following command:
   'AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe /passive'

Note: The order seems to matter - so if you have anything installed already, uninstall and follow the steps above.