# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered in the local machine

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, adodb

I'm getting this error when trying to run a vb application on a another pc. Is there some place I can download this DLL?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en

Answer (score 3):

I had already done that by using AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 as the server is 64 bit - Please see for reference Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en

Comment: +1 for newer (2010/64bit) solution

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the issue of still getting the error *after* installing the [Office 2007 Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en). The issue was because it is 32-bit being invoked by a 64-bit process. Various solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/vb-net-error-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-resolved/2161896)

Answer (score 1):

I found there was a series of steps which I wrote out on a [blog post: the-microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine](http://www.arboundy.com/2010/11/the-microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/).

Answer (score 0):

That is a data provider dll, it appears to be an office driver for accessing Access dbs or  office documents like they were databases.
See here... http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255