# SQL Server 2008 R2 Excel Import

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-import-wizard

I'm using SS 2008 R2 and Office 2010 on a Windows 7 64 bit. I am trying to use the import wizard to import an excel sheet into a table. I get this error:

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)
```

I am very new to this and would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Incidently, I also may be doing this wrong (and therfore getting the error) because if I choose the 64 bit import wizard there is no option for Microsoft Excel. So, I am trying to use the 32 bit wizard. Does anyone know how I can get this to work? Thanks in advance!

For other users:
For anyone who has this same problem, The answer that a1ex07 suggested works for Office 2010 as well. Check this thread [The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered in the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646409/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-in-the-local-machine)

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646409/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-in-the-local-machine

Comment: @a1ex07 Does it not matter that I'm using Office 2010?

Comment: I'll answer that, no it doesn't. It works just fine. @a1ex07 Please put your comment in the answer section so I can give you you rep points and thank you!

Comment: I think you should add a point to the original answer, not to mine :) I just pointed you to it.

Comment: Ok, No problem. Thanks for pointing me to the answer!

Comment: For anyone who has this same problem, The answer that a1ex07 suggested works for Office 2010 as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646409/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-in-the-local-machine

Comment: @kd7 could you answer this question with your answer link http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en so i can give you your points. a1ex07 pointed me to it and doesn't want to take credit. I would like for you to recieve your rep points and have a set answer for this question so users see it in a search. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who has this same problem, The answer that a1ex07 suggested works for Office 2010 as well.  alex07's answer [The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered in the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646409/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-in-the-local-machine)  ...  this answer originally came from kd7.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem trying to import an Excel file using SQL Management Studio (SMS 2012). I use 64-bit version of everything including Office 2013. This solution from social.msdn.microsoft.com solved it for me:

The problem you are likely having is the Import/Export Wizard is being launched as the 32-bit version.  This is probably due to you right clicking on a database and clicking on import and since SSMS is a 32-bit program it will launch 32-bit processes.  Try explicitly running the Import/Export Wizard (64-bit) by clicking on Start->Program Files->Microsoft SQL Server 2012->Import and Export Data (64-bit) to import your data from a 64-bit datasource.

Noral Kuhlmann

Answer (score 0):

the file can be Excel 2007 try to install 2007 Office System Driver: [Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)