# asp.net 4.0 to excel 2010 in command line app not working - drivers not found even after driver install

Tags: asp.net, excel, odbc, adodb

I have 100 excel files. In each file I need one row from it to be inserted into SQL server. I need this automated but ultimately don't care if it is asp.net in an app or excel macros. If you have any ideas, please let me know.

**Issue**
I wrote the asp.net 4.0 command line app code then got the error: The 'Microsoft.Ace.OleDb.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

**Tried**
After I installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable, (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) there are no more odbc drivers on my box. Just the SQL drivers as before.

My box is x64 but I have x86 office installed so I installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable for x86.

I also checked the registry and can't see any drivers but the SQL server drivers.

I've read several articles:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/eeaa2d7b-fbfa-401b-8efe-9170f04059b0

[The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered in the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646409/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-in-the-local-machine)

While I'm going to include my code below, I don't think it makes a difference until I have the drivers -

```
public void ImportExcelFilesForPieChart()
{
    List<DataTable> listDataTables = new List<DataTable>();
    List<CompanyInfo> newlist = new List<CompanyInfo>();
    string sheetName = "Output";

    string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(dropBoxExcelLocation);
    foreach (string filename in fileList)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OleDb.4.0;data source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1", dropBoxExcelLocation + filename);
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string strSQL = String.Format("SELECT 4A, 4B, 4C, 4D, 4E, 4F FROM [{0}$]", sheetName); //[A4:F4]";
            OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
            connection.Open();

            using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, connection))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
                listDataTables.Add(dt);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is IIS running under x64 on your box?

Comment: I'm not running under IIS, I'm running as a console app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did several things so I'm not sure if all the steps are important.

I registered my dlls according to this kb article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805. Before registering them, I verified there were no entries in the registry. This got me to the ISAM not found exception.

Then, thanks to Dave R, I changed my connection string. The final connection string that worked was (notice the escaped quotes on the Extended Properties)

```
string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1\"", filename);
```

I didn't realize the file extension (.xlsx) was relavant to the connection string but after reading the connection string information here (http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007), I fixed it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! The connection strings site looks really useful, too - I'll bookmark that one :)

Comment: Thanks for helping. I was so stuck. It was a HUGE help to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is incorrect.

The provider should be `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

I believe the JET provider is 4.0. Were you trying that beforehand?

Comment: I changed the connection string and now my error is "Cound not find installable ISAM." I'm following this KB now - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209805.