# Trying to connect to excel 2010 doesn't work

Tags: c#, excel-2010

I got this exception:
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I was trying to connect Excel 2010 files with OleDBConnection. I have windows 7 64bit and office 2010 32 bit.

I have tried to install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable which suggested from:
[The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered in the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646409/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-in-the-local-machine)

I also tried this suggestion:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64

Neither one of them works for me. Anyone help?

Here is my code:
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=d:\Sample.xlsx;Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties=\"HDR=YES;\";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37";

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

try
{
    connection.Open();

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.Dump();

}
catch (Exception)
{            
    throw;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a discussion about this error, please refer to it and let me know whether it is worked for you.

[HOW TO FIX](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64)

Best Regards

try installing this first: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

try the following method:

NOTE: this DOES work for office 2010 even though it is for 2007 office

1. download and install this: [Download here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734)
2. in VS click add data source, follow the wizard.

Comment: This information comes from the 2nd article I mentioned. It does not work for me!

Comment: oops.. I did not see that. Let me see if I can get anything.

Comment: @Meidi, Can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179905/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: I have installed that too. It does not work for me. In fact, that's the 1st component I installed and it didn't work. Then I tried the 2007 and didn't work either.

Comment: Do you think that the 32 bit and 64 bit version can be a problem ?

Comment: like in one of the post it says "I installed MS Office 2010 64 Bit and AccessDatabaseEngine 64 Bit and i got the solution to my issue."