# Why does my code stop after "con.Open()"?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

In my code, why does nothing execute after `con.Open()`.
If I step through each step, it ends the `Form1_Load` event after `con.Open()`.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Dim con As OleDbConnection
Dim strCon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=C:\testDB.accdb"

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    con = New OleDbConnection(strCon)

    con.Open()
    MsgBox("con open")

    con.Close()
    MsgBox("con closed")

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like an Error is begin raised.

Have you tried framing your code with `OnError Goto Handler` type code? See the [On Error Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as(VS.80).aspx).

If this is VB.NET, trying catching an exception with `Try ... Catch`. Then set a breakpoint on the `Catch` statements to find out what the error is.

Comment: Put it in a try..catch. It throws some exceptions.  The first is "System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on th local machine.  ??

Comment: Well, that is a problem. You will need to install that driver.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the Mircrosoft Object 12.0 Library reference was it.

Comment: I installed the driver but still get the same exception. ?

Comment: After installing the driver, I had to change the advanced compile configuration because I am running on Windows 7 64 bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/vb-net-error-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-resolved

Comment: @ScottK: you should post the compile options solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I'm assuming he just locked the processor type to 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the MS Access Database Engine (to use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0), my program still did not work.  I still had the error:

> "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local muoteachine."

I *also* had to change the advanced compile configuration because I am running on Windows 7 64 bit and may have "...locked the processor type to 32-bit".

How to change the settings:

1.Tools -> Options.
2.Check "Show all settings".
3.In the tree-view on the left hand side, select "Projects and Solutions".
4.In the options on the right, check the box that says, "Show advanced build configuraions."
5.Click OK.
6.Go to Build -> Configuration Manager...
7.In the Platform column select "new" in the drop down list.
8. Select "x86" under first dropdown box.
9. "Ok"

More info here: [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/vb-net-error-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-resolved)

Comment: **UPDATE:** For Visual Studio 2010, you must go to "Tools", "Settings", and check "Expert Settings" to make "Build" visible to do step 6.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have proper try catch block some time it take several seconds for the con.Open() to throw an exception since it's waiting for the server. Following error takes a while to throw an exception and it will appear as if your Step Into disappeared. Be patient!

"ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred"

Answer (score 0):

Imports System.Data.Odbc

Public Class Form11

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a1, a2, a6, a3, a4, a5, a7 As String
    ' Dim a2, a6 As Integer
    a1 = txtname.Text
    a3 = txtaddress.Text
    a4 = txtcity.Text
    a5 = txtmail.Text
    a7 = txtbalance.Text
    a2 = txtmob.Text
    a6 = txtvehicles.Text
    Dim con As New OdbcConnection("DSN = crusher_schema")
    con.Open()
    MsgBox("Databse Connected", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "add")
    Dim cmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("insert into customer values('" & a1 & "','" & a2 & "','" & a3 & "','" & a4 & "','" & a5 & "','" & a6 & "','" & a7 & "', con")
    Dim r As Integer
    r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    If r = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Succesfully inserted" & r)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not inserted" & r)
    End If!
```

[Form.vb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DoSz.png)