# Application deployment problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-access

I developed an application using VS 2008 and MS Access2007 and it works fine. Now have to make a setup  of it(this is my first project). I gone through many tutorials about deployment, I tried VS 2008 setup and deployment, but after installation it only runs in my machine and not in others..sometimes it shows error(The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine(but that machine had both VS2008 and MS Access installed)). Its over a week now, i tried what i can and still trying, cant believe that i am strucked here, nothing seems to work. Please help...
The link below is my project, so if any of you could spare a little time to check the project and help me with the SetUp.

```
           http://www.4shared.com/file/7G14MULL/_2__GameOnStart.html
```

Thanking You all in advance.
Regards
Indranil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an issue with ADO. You can fix that by setting project to compile as 32 bit application. It could be done by opening the Configuration Manager from the Build. From there you should be able to set the Active solution platform and create configuration that specifically target x86.

Alternatively use Project Properties

```
VB.Net: goto Compile tab, Advanced Compile Options..., Target CPU set x86
C#: goto Build, Platform target and set x86
```

Comment: How to create the configuration that specifically target x86?

Comment: i found the compile tab..but where is Advance Compile Options?

Comment: only Compile Options is there

Comment: On Compile tab, all the way down, there is button "Advance Compile Options..."

Comment: my mistake..how couldnt i noticed that...thanks for being patience :)
Done, next?

Comment: Volody, jus to make sure
new project->setUp and Deplyment->Setup Project->add files(debug) to Users Desktop->build-> run the setup...is the way?

Comment: same problem persists :(
could u download d project and check..i would really be grateful.

Comment: you can check similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-resolved