# "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered

Tags: c#, excel

When I use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to access an Excel file, Is Office 2007 required to be installed on the machine or it is enough if just the just Access Database Engine is instaled ?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered" \[RESOLVED\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-resolved)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to install the redistributable for Jet.

See: [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-resolved)