# how to connect to access 2007 with c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string, database-connection

hey,
i am new at connecting to dataBases and for some reason each time i use those following lines my program collapse:

```
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\Company.accdb"
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```

inside my debug folder i got Company.accdb access file 
edit:
i am getting 'Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine any idea how to solve it? 
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: well, you're datasource property doesn't look too good?

Comment: well i didnt want to show the all code its alittle bit too much to show i know that the program collapse there ... when i put try and catch over it i get the following exception: "the type initializer threw an exception which doesnt say much

Comment: DataSource=|DataDirectory| is the directory inside the debug where my access file is

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things -

1. This connection string rely on ACE OLEDB provider (typically comes with Office 2007 - your machine need to have this provider)
2. Connection string is requesting data dictionary. You probably need to use below form:

   Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;

For password protected files, form would be `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;`

I will also suggest trying different Provider (ODBC perhaps) instead. For various connection strings for Access 2007, refer http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007

Comment: i am getting 'Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @Nadav, as said, this component typically comes with office 2007. Anyway, you can download it from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891&displaylang=en

Comment: Apparently, there are other reasons for this error other than that it is not installed (see OP comment).

Comment: @Remou, you are of course correct! But then you had already pointed out as such to OP so no point in repeating here. Hopefully, either should solve OP's issue.

Comment: @VinayC I have noticed that people selectively read threads, some skip the original question, some skip most of the answers. The comment is not so much for you or the OP as for any others that may read this thread in the future.

Comment: @Remou: are you talking to me? ARE YOU TALKING TO ME? ;)