# Microsoft Access 2007 Database Connection in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, database-connection, ms-access-2007

I am new in creating application in Visual Studio 2010. I recently created an application which has a MySQL as a database. Now, I am creating an app where I used a MS Access 2007 as a database.

I have this code for the database connection of MySQL:

```
class DBConn
{
    string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=payroll;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=admin;";
    public DataTable retrieveRecord(string cmd)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(cmd, con);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        con.Open();
        DataSet set = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(set);
        con.Close();
        return set.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

My problem now is that how to change this code to access the database of MS Access 2007? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the connection string to something like this: "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\yourdatabase.mdb;User Id=username;Password=password;"

Comment: if the database is .mdb use this answer but if it is 2007 .accdb use answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427523/how-to-connect-to-access-2007-with-c-sharp