# System.Exception: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#

I am trying to access the data from MS Access Database using C#. in my system i am able to access it. Where in server i am getting this error:

> Error : -2147467259: System.Exception:
>   The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
>   provider is not registered on the
>   local machine.

In my system I've installed MS Office 2010 and in server it is 2003 is it because of that?

Both the systems are windows 2008 R2 and 64 bit

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this library comes with Access, which you may not have installed on your server?

If not, try downloading the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d&displaylang=en) .

Comment: I downloaded Microsoft Access Database Engine and it is working fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change target platform to x86 in project > properties > build.

Answer (score 1):

The following could help"

[Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered)

[The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered](http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2007/11/16/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-error-with-vista-64bit.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In this link you can find the 64 bits version of the 'Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable':
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
You only can install it if you remove any 32 bits versions of office components.