# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered

Tags: c#, ms-access, 64-bit

My application is written in `C#` and uses `Ms-Access 2003` and I want it to run properly in `64-bit` Windows installation. I use the data provider as `ACE.OLEDB.12.`0 in the connection string, but it still gives the exception that `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider is not registered though I have installed the `Microsoft Access Databse Engine 2010` (`32-bit`) in the target machine (As the target machine's `Office` installation is `32-bit`).

I followed to the following post [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered)
and many other posts in `msdn` and other `microsoft` sites and the problem solves as they say to compile to `x86`. I want to know whether there is another way of solving this problem which does not require compiling to `x86`...

Comment: No - I don't think that there is another robust solution...

Comment: Must your app be compiled as 64-bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to compile for x86, but you need to install the 64-bit Access OLEDB provider on a 64-bit box. It's available here: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255)

Comment: doesn't that conflict with an installed 32 Bit Office on the same machine ?

Comment: I tried to install it, but it says that the available Office version is 32-bit, thus cannot be installed and the setup exits...

Comment: @Yahia - you don't have the choice anyway if you want 64-bit support, but it should work. There maybe a trick to ensure you can install it correctly. See this link and the remark about the "passive" install trick: http://blog.codefluententities.com/2011/01/20/microsoft-access-database-engine-2010-redistributable/

Comment: @ Simon Mourier: Yeah, it installs fine with /passive and works well!!! Thank you loads...

Comment: @Simon Mourier: Thanks for the /passive trick. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue on a 64-bit, but following advice on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine, I installed the Office 2007 version of these components from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734, which worked flawlessly.