# OleDb connection to Access 2013 database

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledbconnection

I have a program that reads from and writes to an Access database. It works fine on my own computer but when I tried to download it on a new computer that has the new Office 2013 programs it said that the provider in connection string didn't work. Here's my connection string:

```csharp
string filepath = @"C:\FamilyFoundations\ProvidentLiving\App\Data\"; // Hold the path to the file
string dbPath = filepath + "GoalsDB.accdb"; // Holds the name of our data base

// string to create our database
string db = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dbPath + "; JET OLEDB:Engine Type=5";'
```

Does my string need to be changed or is there something I need to download on my friends computer? My first thought is that there is a new Microsoft.JET that I need to include, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Is your project targeted to the 32-bit ("x86") platform as described in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19686200/2144390)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's target platform is any CPU but prefers 32 bit

Comment: Well, you could try setting the target platform to *just* x86 and see if that helps.

Comment: @GordThompson Same error message. Do I need to download the .net file on his computer?

Comment: Which ".NET file" would that be?

Comment: Sorry I meant the framework. For example my program  uses the .NET Framework 4.5. Do I need to download some sort of a converter file?