# OLEDB Connection using without physically installing the driver

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have been trying to access the MS Access database file residing on my machine and it works just fine when I have office installed.

When I try to use the same code on a machine that does not have office installed/driver installed it throws up an error "**Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered**"

I followed up on this post [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170491/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered) but the solution here is to install the redistributable physically.while I would like to do it programmatically using C#.

Would that be possible only by installation physically, is this the only way out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your application uses the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` driver then that driver must be installed on the machine. To (directly) access the database file "programmatically using C#" would essentially involve you (re-)writing [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) in C#. That would be a *huge* amount of work and would make no real sense (since the proper ACE.OLEDB driver for Windows is already freely available).

One alternative would be to use the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` driver instead. The (32-bit) Jet driver is installed with every copy of Windows. However, you would face the following restrictions:

1. Your application would only be able to manipulate `.mdb` files, not `.accdb` files, and
2. Your application would have to be built as a 32-bit application.