# Uploading excel on Windows Server (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered on local machine)

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, oledbconnection

I'm trying to upload an excel file.

I have an ASP.NET test site on my local machine,where the upload works fine.

However, when I put the same site onto a server machine and then try to upload, it gives me an error message:
**"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered on local machine"**

Here is my connection string (for localhost):

```
cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fullpathname + ";Extended Properties=;Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1");
```

This works on the server with (Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0) but the same gives an error on my local host, so its vice-versa:

```
cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fullpathname + ";Extended Properties=;Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1");
```

I have tried to google this but couldn't find a good solution, tried of some of the answers like changing the build configuration,still doesn't work. Right now in my visual studio the build configuration is set to **"Any CPU"**  (with reference to this [SO:Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered))

My server machine does not have Microsoft office installed, could that be a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload first your Excel file on your server then your method will read that excel file located on you server.

[Read and Display Data From an Excel File (.xsl or .xlsx) in ASP.NET](http://www.tipsntracks.com/100/read-and-display-data-from-an-excel-file-xsl-or-xlsx-in-aspnet.html)

Share “YourFileFolder” where excel file will be uploaded and add ‘Network Service’ account having read/write permission

Regards

Comment: I'm trying to upload it, and save it's data into the database. I don't want to display it

Comment: ..i just attached an example..you can follow the uploading and reading of excel file..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, After some googling I got the solution for the issue.
I rectified the issue by installing the "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components" in the link below.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734