# Deploy ACCESS OleDb driver

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, database-connection

I've tried to deploy a small website (ASP.NET) which is using an MS ACCESS 2010 db. Deploying the website on the server I get the following error:

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

Connectionstring used : `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=path-to-db`

MS Office is not installed on the server and neither is the Access Database engine. The website is runnin in a shared hosting environment, so I am not able to install office on that server, so may I somehow deploy the provider by dll's?

Is it possible to deploy the drivers needed for ASP.Net to connect to the database without having to run an installation on the server. As this is in a shared hosting environment, I am not able to install anything. Only fileupload by ftp.

Comment: I reckon you would have a better chance asking in http://serverfault.com. Stackoverflow is a programming-related site, and you question does not appear to fall into that category.

Comment: Thank you, @Remou. I'll post my question there. I was not aware of that forum.

Answer (score 1):

Open IIS, navigate to Application Pools, find the appPool for your website, right click, advanced settings, set "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to true.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around, this has nothing to do with Office. If you're only using Access as the database, then you don't need to install it. Info here: http://www.mytechsupport.ca/forums/index.php?topic=11237.0

I found this StackOverflow thread with the same error you did so it sounds like it might be the same issue. [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered)

If its running windows then look through that thread and see if the 64-bit issue is the problem. I've had this same issue before and its apparently quite common. You may need to e-mail whoever for support on your server.

Is it running Linux? If it is running linux then the issue might be just an entire lack of the driver to connect to Access databases. If this is the case I would e-mail your support and ask them if they can install the proper drivers for you. Info here: http://nixcraft.com/databases-servers/11878-connect-microsoft-access-database-php-linux-server.html

Comment: Re your first link: if you use an *MDB*, then you don't need to install anything (though you need to be running as 32-bit).  That thread is from 2006, before Access 2007 introduced the ACCDB format and the associated ACE OLEDB drivers.

Comment: This is not a 64 bit issue. This is on connecting to a accdb (access) database withouth having the drivers installed. How to deploy the drivers on a shared hosting website