# How to register Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider on local machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, oledb

I'm writing to a 2007 Microsoft Access file and when I do it using Visual Studio 2012, I have no issues at all. Everything reads and writes just fine, but when I publish the project and put it on IIS, I get an error message saying that the OLEDB provider isn't registered on the local machine. I've downloaded every Microsoft AccessDatabaseEngine.exe that's been suggested, all with zero success. Do I need to do anything other than just download and run the setup?

Comment: Do you have the provider at your host? This might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered?rq=1

Comment: You installed the 2010 redistributable from Microsoft? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Kevin, yes I've installed that to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The IIS app pool needed to be set to accept 32-bit applications. Once I changed the setting from false to true, it worked perfectly!!! Thanks to Matt who provided detailed instructions on how to change the setting on the thread linked at the top. Helped me out immensely!