# Error in Connect to the Access Database In Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I made a Database in access and i saved it in my Desktop
then in Data Grid View I clicked Choose Data Source and then Clicked Add Project Data Source...
Then I Clicked New Connection and i choose Microsoft Access Database File (OLE DB)
then I Choose My Database From Desktop...
Now What user name & password I have to write???My Username & Pass in windows???
I Clicked Test Connection then a message Show :

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

What can i do??
Thank You So much :X

Comment: You need to start by clearly identifying what your problem is. Please take your time to describe in as much detail as possible, possibly including some screenshots.

Comment: Thanks For Help...Screen Shot : http://up.ashiyane.org/images/4xypo85e0m4bojsg4g5.png

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered

Comment: The address has been blocked by my antivirus. Please use a different image host.

Comment: Can You Describe more PLZ???

Comment: Screen: http://www.uploadscenter.com/3xtzpiymy546

Comment: what is the extension of your database file? is it .mdb or .accdb?