# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine on MVC Applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oledb

I am getting Error Message "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine" when I try make a connection with OleDbConnection to MDB file.

I have try most popular solution for this error.
1. Install Microsoft Access Database Engine
2. Change Platform Target on Build Tab from Project Properites.

Problem has not been solved.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition Version 12.0.2.10051.1
Operation System Windows 8 Pro ( x64 )

P.S. : I can make same connection on Command Applications. I just have this error on Web Applications.

Comment: 3. Use a 32-bit application pool.

Comment: Or install 64-bit version of the driver

Comment: Tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered?rq=1#answer-2648640

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Answer (score 0):

in iis7 or heigher on a 64 bit windows,app pool has a config :enable 32 bit application(i'm sorry ,i'm not use english windows,i'm not sure what it name),it default is false,change it to true
find the pool,right click,enter advance config,you can search a config means enable 32 bit app