# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-excel

I am trying to use linq_to_excel

http://www.softinterface.com/DL/DL_UserData_Proc.ASP

This is my code:

```
var data = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory();
            data.FileName= @"FRM_DTA.xlsx";
            data.AddMapping<ExcelFileDefinition>(x => x.FARM_ID, "FRM_ID");
            data.AddMapping<ExcelFileDefinition>(x => x.FARM_OWNER, "FRM_OWNER");
            data.AddMapping<ExcelFileDefinition>(x => x.FARM_AREA_ID, "FRM_AREA_ID");
            data.AddMapping<ExcelFileDefinition>(x => x.FARM_EMARA_ID, "FRM_EMARA_ID");
            data.AddMapping<ExcelFileDefinition>(x => x.FARM_REGION_ID, "FRM_REGION_ID");
            data.AddMapping<ExcelFileDefinition>(x => x.FARM_NUMBER, "farmNumber");
            data.AddMapping<ExcelFileDefinition>(x => x.RECEIVING_CENTER_ID, "RecievingCentreID");
            var result = from x in data.Worksheet<ExcelFileDefinition>()
                         select x;
            (foreach(var row in result){
                Console.WriteLine(row.FARM_ID);
            }
```

when I run it, I got this exception:

```
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

Help please

#### What I have tried

I found this question [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered) and I changed my `platform target` from `any cpu` to `x86` but still have the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Download and install Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: I install it but still have the same exception

Comment: Which version? X86 or X64? Is there any Office installed (x86 or x64?)?

Answer (score 4):

I needed to download Office 2007 System Driver: Data Connectivity Components version: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734