# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine happens in other computers

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am developing a software using VB .NET in a computer running Windows 7 32-bit OS.

The software contains those lines of code as shown below:

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection

cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fileNameStr & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxx"

cn.Open()
```

The codes above open a Microsoft Access file (extension: mdb), which is protected by a password.

In my computer (32 bit Windows 7), the codes work fine.

However, when I test this software in other computers (64 bit Windows 7), I got the error message as shown below:
[image: Error message]

I have tried to install another driver called "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" in those computers getting the error message, however it does not solve the problem.

Can you suggest where my mistakes are and how to resolve them?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/238625/1070452

Comment: google.com?q=site:stackoverflow.com "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

Comment: Read @Plutonix's post ! Is about 64 bit platform !

Comment: There is a specific driver for MS Access on x64 machines that is not installed by default. Do some searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your application to compile under x86 and not AnyCPU or x64.  To do this in VB:

1. Right click on your project in the solution explorer and choose properties (or go under the "Project" menu and select "Properties"
2. Click on the compile tab
3. Change the "Target CPU" drop down to be x86.