# OleDbConnection with MsAccess using C#

Tags: c#, windows, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I'm trying to connect ms access database using c#. While doing that I'm stuck at one place.

Whenever i try to open the connection using

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("connection string valid");
conn.Open();
```

I get error that whichever is the provider, it is not registered onto the local machine !

I have downloaded the msaccessEngine also from well known link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/238625/1070452 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6649363/1070452 plus at least 2 or 3 MSDN articles

Comment: Are you running excel in 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered this solve my problem ! Thanks a lot Plutonix

Comment: Can you please post your full error message?