# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine in NUnit

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, nunit

I have NUnit installed on my 64 bit Windows 7 machine and office 2010 (32bit).
I tried reading excel file(.xls) using oledb data reader and it works fine in Visual Studio 2013. I have added app.config file for this.
Now the problem occurs in NUnit when I tried running this dll in it. It gives above error. I tried all the solutions like compiling in x64 and installing 
this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255.

I am trying hard to resolve this problem. Can anyone help me out with this?

Machine : Windows 7 (64 - bit)
Office : 2010 (32 - bit)

Comment: Did you tried all these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered ?

Comment: Yes. But its not working. I found one solution in which its working but giving problem for office. Check this link http://techblog.aimms.com/2014/10/27/installing-32-bit-and-64-bit-microsoft-access-drivers-next-to-each-other/

Comment: Why is this question tagged with WebDriver?  AFAICT, it is unrelated.

Comment: yes you are right, its a mistake.