# the microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered windows 8.1 office 2016 vb .net

Tags: mysql, windows, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OytQU.png)

When I click on the button ADD, I got the following error:

The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I have no clue how to fix this. My operating system is Windows 8.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238625/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered) Please do a thorough search of the site before posting a new question, as chances are quite good that you're not the only one to have experienced the error. In this case, a simple search for the error message found the duplicate as the first result.

Comment: Check you've got the right version installed too.  Some 32bit odbc drives will not work with 64bit apps and vice versa

Comment: @Hursey s/some/all (and this is OLEDB not ODBC).